# How to save global variable value from parse database

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I have a table (Gtree) in parse database, one-to-one relationship with Users. How can I get value (content which related with current user) and save into global variable?

```
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
var Gtree = Parse.Object.extend("Gtree");
var output = "";

function loadTree() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Gtree);
    query.include("user");
    query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i in results) {
                var content = results[i].get("content");
                var user = results[i].get("user");
                var username = user.get("username");
                var id = results[i].id;
                output = content;
                console.log("CONTENT:" + content);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Query Error:" + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Not clear what and where should be saved. What is the exact problem?

Comment: i need to save value from Gtree.content in var output

Answer (score 0):

`query.find()` returns a `Parse.Promise` object and it's simpler to cache and return that, rather than the actual result(s).

You probably want something like this.

```
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
var Gtree = Parse.Object.extend("Gtree");

var promiseCache = {};

function loadTree() {
    if(!promiseCache.gtree_user) {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Gtree);
        query.include("user");
        query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
        promiseCache.gtree_user = query.first().then(function(result) {
            return {
                content: result.get("content"),
                user: result.get("user"),
                username: result.get("user").getUsername(),
                id: result.id
            };
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Query Error:" + error.message);
            return error;
        });
    }
    return promiseCache.gtree_user;
}
```

That way, any call of `loadTree()` is guaranteed to be returned a promise and the user data can be accessed only via promise methods, for example :

```
loadTree().then(function(userData) {
    // userData.content, userData.user, userData.username, userData.id are available here
}, function(error) {
    // handle error case hare
});
```

Please also note that the global namespace should be avoided as it's prone to name collisions and security leaks. The above code would be better wrapped in eg. a self-executing function or an onload event handler.